# Extracted .wav file from .mp4 video with ffmpeg only has half of the duration

Tags: ffmpeg

I've been using ffmpeg to extract .wav files from .mp4 videos to then generate waveforms and spectrograms for it, but I stumbled upon a file for which ffmpeg does not generate the full audio file. The video duration is 25:25 (25 minutes and 25 seconds), but the .wav file is 12:28 (12 minutes and 28 seconds).

This is what I've been doing:

```
C:\Users\<user>> ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -ab 160k -ac 1 -ar 44100 -vn audio.wav
```

I tried with `-ac 2` only to see if I get something different, but the result is the same. In fact, I can't generate the plots I need with a stereo audio file.

This is what I get in the terminal when I run the command:

```
C:\Users\<user>>ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -ab 160k -ac 1 -ar 44100 -vn audio.wav
ffmpeg version 4.3 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9.3.1 (GCC) 20200621
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libdav1d --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libsrt --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libgsm --disable-w32threads --enable-libmfx --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libopenmpt --enable-amf
  libavutil      56. 51.100 / 56. 51.100
  libavcodec     58. 91.100 / 58. 91.100
  libavformat    58. 45.100 / 58. 45.100
  libavdevice    58. 10.100 / 58. 10.100
  libavfilter     7. 85.100 /  7. 85.100
  libswscale      5.  7.100 /  5.  7.100
  libswresample   3.  7.100 /  3.  7.100
  libpostproc    55.  7.100 / 55.  7.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'audio.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp42mp41
    creation_time   : 2021-03-09T05:00:00.000000Z
  Duration: 00:25:25.29, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2308 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1280x720, 4410 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 30k tbn, 59.94 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2021-03-09T05:00:00.000000Z
      handler_name    : ?Mainconcept Video Media Handler
      encoder         : AVC Coding
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 253 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2021-03-09T05:00:00.000000Z
      handler_name    : #Mainconcept MP4 Sound Media Handler
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:0 (aac (native) -> pcm_s16le (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Output #0, wav, to 'audio.wav':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp42mp41
    ISFT            : Lavf58.45.100
    Stream #0:0(eng): Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 44100 Hz, mono, s16, 705 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2021-03-09T05:00:00.000000Z
      handler_name    : #Mainconcept MP4 Sound Media Handler
      encoder         : Lavc58.91.100 pcm_s16le
size=   64463kB time=00:12:28.41 bitrate= 705.6kbits/s speed= 156x
video:0kB audio:64463kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.000118%
```

If this information on the video is not enough to troubleshoot, the video says the following (when it starts, for the first few seconds):

```
EP TRT (23.976): 01:24:53:18
EP TRT (29.976): 01:24:55:06

AUDIO LAYOUT

Channel 1: Left Front (L)
Channel 2: Right Front (R)
Channel 3: Center (C)
Channel 4: Low Frequency/Effects (LFE)
Channel 5: Left Surround (Ls)
Channel 6: Right Surround (Rs)
Channel 7: Mono Mix (L)
Channel 8: Mono Mix (R)
```

This is for TV, that's why you see that longer duration. I don't know if all this is relevant, actually.

**Some additional info**

Something curious is that I'm doing this for manual tests, but I'm actually creating an app with python and, for that, I'm using `python-ffmpeg` module, and I with that I'm getting the correct .wav file (with the correct duration). The python lines for this are the following:

```py
(
                        ffmpeg
                        .input(
                            <input_path>
                        )
                        .output(
                            <output_path.wav>,
                            audio_bitrate=316000,
                            ac=1,
                            ar=48000
                        )
                        .run()
)
```

Comment: Very strange. Can you share the original  "video.mp4"?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't because I'm bound by an NDA. I'll keep trying to reproduce the error with a video I can share.